# Change right to user with escape character

Tags: sql-server-2008, access-rights

I would  like to execute the following query :

```
DENY DELETE ON tableTest to Domain\Username
```

but it prints

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '\'.
```

i tried

```
SELECT @Test = 'Domain\Username'    
DENY DELETE ON tableTest to @Test
```

but it also didn't work.
The Domain\Username is the value i get in sys.database_principals

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[]` to be able to use otherwise invalid characters for [identifiers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx):

```
DENY DELETE ON tableTest to [Domain\Username]
```